# Is there a shortcut to query a tree?

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I need to retrieve data that is in a typical tree structure in the application.

- Project (Branch)

  - Branch Level 2 (1)

  - Branch Level 2 (2)

    - Branch Level 3 (1)

      - Task

    - Branch Level 3 (2)
    - Branch Level 3 (3)

  - Branch Level 2 (3)

Each Branch references a Limb and the Limb may reference another Branch to create the tree.  Then tasks also reference a Branch ID.  Limbs are sort of an invisible layer.  They do not appear in tree that's displayed in the application, so I did not include them in the structure above.

I need to find a Branch with the project name and find data about a specific task that is below it in the tree.

Currently, I have a query that looks for the task at a specific depth in the tree.  This makes the query get bulky pretty quickly and also makes it fail to find data if a project has a different tree structure.  Here is an example looking for a task that is 3 levels below the main project branch.

```
select
     b.VersionID, 
     b.name as "ProjectName", 
     t.name as "TaskName", 
     t.DueDate
from  Branch b
     ,Limb l
     ,Branch b2
     ,Limb l2
     ,Branch b3
     ,Limb l3
     ,Branch b4
     ,task t
where 
      b.name = 'B654321'
  and t.name = 'Deliver Draft Report to Project Director'
  and b.VersionID = l.VersionID  
  and b.id = l.Branch
  and l.id = b2.Limb
  and l.VersionID = b2.VersionID  
  and b2.id = l2.Branch
  and b2.VersionID = l2.VersionID  
  and l2.id = b3.Limb
  and l2.VersionID = b3.VersionID  
  and b3.id = l3.Branch
  and b3.VersionID = l3.VersionID  
  and l3.id = b4.Limb
  and l3.VersionID = b4.VersionID  
  and b4.id = t.Branch
  and b.VersionID = t.VersionID
```

So, my question is this:  Is there any "shortcut"/trick to get the query to traverse the tree to find a task with a specified name that is somewhere below the project branch, regardless of it's relative location/depth?

I'm sure this has been answered before, but I've searched and come up for any answers that have been helpful, since this is not a standard hierarchy with the table referring back to itself.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: DDL statements for minimal versions of your tables; DML statements for some sample data within those tables; your expected result; an English (not code) explanation of how to get from the the sample data to the result. Its very hard to read someone else's code and try to understand the problem (and not get sucked down the same rabbit hole that they went down) but its much easier to look at data to get an idea of the problem. So, please help us to help you by providing something we can just copy/paste and execute to get a handle on the problem

Comment: look at CONNECT BY

Comment: Your hierarchy at the at the top goes `branch1 > branch2 > branch3 > limb` but reading your code it seems to go `branch1 > limb1 > branch2 > limb2 > branch3 > limb3`; these two hierarchies don't align. Also, you have a table alias `e` in your `WHERE` clause but there is no table with the alias `e` in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: @MT0 Thank you for the feedback.  I will try to do better next time.  I updated the post to better explain the hierarchical relationship and the absence of the "limbs" in the diagram an I replaced the "e" alias that should not have been there.

Answer (score 2):

Join the `branch` to the `limb` table and then use a hierarchical query (using `CONNECT BY`) to traverse the hierarchy. Something like:

```sql
WITH branch_limb ( branch_id, limb_id, VersionID, ProjectName ) AS ( 
  SELECT b.id,
         l.id,
         b.VersionID,
         b.name
  FROM   branch b
         INNER JOIN limb l
         ON (   b.id        = l.branch
            AND b.VersionID = l.VersionID )
),
branch_limb_hierarchy ( branch_id, limb_id, VersionID, ProjectName ) AS (
  SELECT branch_id,
         limb_id,
         VersionID,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT( ProjectName )
  FROM   branch_limb
  START WITH ProjectName = 'B654321'
  CONNECT BY
         PRIOR limb_id   = branch_id
  AND    PRIOR VersionID = VersionID
)
SELECT b.VersionID,
       b.ProjectName,
       t.name AS TaskName,
       t.DueDate
FROM   branch_limb_hierarchy b
       INNER JOIN task t
       ON (   b.branch_id = t.Branch
          AND b.VersionID = t.VersionID )
WHERE  t.name = 'Deliver Draft Report to Project Director'
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had to tinker with it to get it to work, but that gave me the start I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using the framework provided by @MT0 as a base, here's where I ended up:

```
WITH branch_limb ( branch_id, branch_limb, limb_id, limb_branch, VersionID, ProjectName ) AS ( 
  SELECT b.id,
         b.limb,
         limb.id,
         limb.branch,
         b.VersionID,
         b.name
  FROM   branch b
         INNER JOIN limb l
         ON (   b.limb = l.id
            AND b.VersionID = l.VersionID )
),
branch_limb_hierarchy ( branch_id, branch_limb, limb_id, limb_branch, VersionID, ProjectName ) AS (
  SELECT branch_id,
         branch_limb,
         limb_id,
         limb_branch,
         VersionID,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT( ProjectName )
  FROM   branch_limb
  START WITH ProjectName = 'B648236'
  CONNECT BY
         PRIOR branch_id = limb_branch
  AND    PRIOR VersionID = VersionID
)
SELECT distinct
       b.VersionID,
       b.ProjectName,
       t.name AS TaskName,
       t.LINKABLE_START
FROM   branch_limb_hierarchy b
       INNER JOIN task t
       ON (   b.branch_id = t.branch
          AND b.VersionID = t.VersionID )
WHERE  t.name = 'Deliver Draft Report to Project Director'
```